# How to disable button when input is empty with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vuejs. I'm trying to disable a button when an input field is empty.

What I'm trying:

```
<div>
    <input v-model="discount" type="text">
    <button v-bind:class="{ 'opacity-25': discount === '' }" v-bind:disabled="discount.length === 0">Apply</button>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data () {
        return {
            discount: ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Note: This input is out of `<div id="app">`.

Comment: This should work. What's the problem ?

Comment: Have you added `discount` as a data prop to your component? In general it would be helpful to show the entire component, not just the template part.

Comment: this not work. the class opacity-25 doesn't apply on the button when the input is empty.

Comment: Works for me. Class is applied as well. https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/abNKNxG?editors=1111

Comment: Sorry. This input is out of <div id="app">. Thank you all for the support.

Comment: Vue only has control over elements within the root instance. The answer is to move the above markup to be within `<div id="app">`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a single negation with your data property.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      discount: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    btnClicked() {
      console.log(this.discount)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <input v-model="discount" type="text">
  <button v-bind:disabled="!discount" @click="btnClicked">Apply</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I can see you're checking the length of the data 'discount' when really you just need to check if it's false or not.

Change your button html to the below

```html
<button v-bind:class="{ 'opacity-25': discount === '' }" v-bind:disabled="!discount">Apply</button>
```

It should work with checking the length of the variable too, but not necessary if you just want to check whether it has a value or not.